# Why is the Non-null assertion operator "!" needed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an interface with an `optional` key `c`:

```
interface MyInterface {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c?: number;
}

const obj: MyInterface = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
};

const keys : Array<keyof MyInterface> = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

---

The next line, produce a type error, despite checking that `obj[key]` is defined:

*`Object is possibly 'undefined'.`*

```
const res = keys.some((key) => (obj[key] !== undefined && obj[key] > 0))
```

---

#### Check `key` is defined:

Does not work, `key` is, obviously, always defined.

```
const res = keys.some((key) => (key && obj[key] !== undefined && obj[key] > 0))
```

---

#### Use non-null `!` operator:

The workaround is:

```
const res = keys.some((key) => (obj[key] !== undefined && obj[key]! > 0))
```

---

why is that the case?

[Typescript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlk4AuZEAVwFsAjaAbhOXspoedYQH4O6jKCwC%20RIggD2IAM5hkk%20gCtKGbJFiIUAXkKsKyAAwAaVuyOmRLCdLnIA1hHQzklAIJQocdAB5H6SRg0LBxNJAA%20ZF0AbQByOFjjZFj6WIBdawB6TOQoCFpJADcUMAALFAADAEIKhQAHaDgwSSgbWXk8l11-GQA6GUlaCAAKYf8ASijI4cUlaP805CrtXWoQABMIGFAIdeQAMn2FZXmnNKrkSMNx8aIgA)

Comment: There are several previous versions of this question, so I'll go look for one to use as a close target. But basically, TypeScript doesn't perfectly narrow object properties in all situations. Copy `obj[key]` to a constant and then check that: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTk4AuZEAVwFsAjaAbhLIatsZbdIQH5O9JlFYBfIkQQB7EAGcwyaQwBWVDNkixEKALyFe5KgAYANIY7IzRMaymyFyANYR0cqgEEoUOOgA8LujSMGhYONpIAHzI+gDaAERw8abI8QzxALp2APTZyFAQdNIAbihgABYoAAYAhFVKAA7QcGDSUPbyigVyMc6ucgB0ctJ0EAAUY4EAlDHRxGTIMp3IxXAANjR6SqqxgVmGBWA0UCAr65vINbr6NCAAJhAwoBB3yABkb2cbKNHG4lPMIA

Comment: E.g.: `const value = obj[key]; return value !== undefined && value > 0;`

Comment: That's some unexpected and weird behavior. Thanks.